# css for displaying div tag

Tags: html, css

I want to display three div tags b1,b2,b3 inside a container div tag asn box.
I want to display the b1,b2,b3 div tag where I marked in green color.But now it displayed in position which i marked in red color.I already worked with similar concept.That code is not help for me .Now I just tried for one div b1.

```css
.box{
  height:500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
}  
.b1{
  width:250px;
  height:175px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #0000A0;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 0px 0 50px;
  float:left; 
}
```

```html
     <div class="box">
         <div class="b1">
         </div>  <!--end of emp div --> 
         <div class="b2">
         </div>  <!--end of cli div --> 
         <div class="b3">
         </div>  <!--end of doc div -->  
     </div> <!--end of box div -->
```

[image]

Comment: exchange `padding` and `margin`

Comment: b2 and b3 classes? as @mmgross wrote: padding is "inside" the div (the border), margin outside it. So border will draw 0 pixels from parent (upper and left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? I've changed the `box` to `wrap`, but added the `box` class to each of your boxes. Further, I've defined a width in % for each box and added the property `diplay: inline-block` instead of `float:left`.

**NOTE: Please view the snippet full-page**

```css
html,
body,
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  width: 25%;
  height: 175px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box b1">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of emp div -->
  <div class="box b2">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of cli div -->
  <div class="box b3">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of doc div -->
</div>
<!--end of box div -->
```

Comment: I want to leave some space above the box

Comment: you could add a `margin-top` to the `.box` class.

Comment: Ya margin-top is working.but I want to leave some space among each div

Answer (score 4):

```css
.wrap {
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  width: 25%;
  margin-top:5px;
  height: 175px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #0000A0;
  padding: 10px 0px 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box b1">
  </div>
  <!--end of emp div -->
  <div class="box b2">
  </div>
  <!--end of cli div -->
  <div class="box b3">
  </div>
  <!--end of doc div -->
</div>
<!--end of box div -->
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```css
.wrap { 
    padding: 10px 0; 
    background: green;
}
.box {
    width: 80%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.b {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1%;
    background: white;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><div class="box">
    <div class="b1 b"></div>
    <!--end of emp div -->
    <div class="b2 b"></div>
    <!--end of cli div -->
    <div class="b3 b"></div>
    <!--end of doc div -->
</div></div>
<!--end of box div -->
```